# Interactions terms and the dummy variables

Tags: interaction, multicollinearity

I am attempting to model monthly retail electricity sales. To account for both the effects of seasonality and weather, I created an interaction term by multiplying 12 monthly dummy variables by the corresponding month's max temperature, such that:

```
Jan_dum_temp = Jan_dum * Jan_max_temp, 
Feb_dum_temp = Feb_dum * Feb_max_temp, 
.
.
. 
Dec_dum_temp = Dec_dum * Dec_max_temp
```

The resulting model will be:

```
y(hat) = b1 + b2Jan_dum_temp + b3Feb_dum_temp + ... + b13Dec_dum_temp + 
  other explanatory variables
```

When adding these interaction terms to the regression, should I leave one interaction term out to avoid the dummy variable trap? If possible, please provide a source for your answer.

Comment: What do you think?  Does your regression allow a constant?  If so, what might it mean?

Comment: Yes, there is a constant within my model. I do not think I should exclude one of the 12 monthly interaction terms because I have not run into the problem of perfect multicollinearity, especially after reviewing the table of 'Correlations of Parameter Estimates'.

Comment: Yes, leave it out (or else your solver will semi-randomly omit one of the months). Think about the interprettaion of `Feb_dum_temp`: it is a difference in effect of temperature from February to January.

Comment: My solver has not omitted one of the interaction terms when running the regression.  However, when I manually omit the Jan_dum_temp interaction term and only include the following 11 monthly interaction terms, is the constant interpreted as the effect of January's interaction term?

Comment: Or maybe better asked, when omitting January's interaction term, how do I interpret the effects of January's seasonality and weather?

Comment: If you can keep the constant and your suggested 12 month/temperature interaction terms without getting colinearity problems and where the coefficients are interpretable then that seems a good approach.  I would have thought that also adding 11 monthly dummies without temperature might also be worth considering

Comment: I believe Henry's suggestion is the strongest. I will proceed by including 11 monthly dummy variables and a 2-month moving average of the temperature variable to account for the effects of seasonality and temperature.